# meteor cross template user object

Tags: templates, meteor

I'm wondering as user() is an Object that can be used all over

what would be the best and secure way to make it available across all tempaltes ?

{{app.user}} doesn't seem to work

or should I put in Session ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a universal handlebar helper in your client javascript such as :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('user',function(){
   return Meteor.user();
});
```

And anywhere in your templates use it as long as the user is logged in, for instance (if you have a profile name set up):

```
{{user.profile.name}}
```